# How can I automate this process on excel?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel screenshot]

I'm trying to delete values on an Excel sheet that cancel each other out.

I will always have a column with "saldo" meaning balance (debit - credit).
But then, to do what I want, I need to set that column from largest to smallest, create a column with the absolute value to the right and set that from largest to smallest, and then create 3 more columns with the following formulas

1. `IF(O3+O4=0;"delete";"ok")`
2. `IF(AND(O3<0;Q2="delete");"delete";"ok")`
3. `IF(OR(Q3="delete";R3="delete");"delete";"ok")`

(See image to see reference cells)

I then filter the last column by "delete" and delete all values that cancel each other out, but this may take a lot of tries because values can be in this form:

```
10
10
10
-10
-10
-10
```

So I have to basically apply the 3 formulas again, and filter again, and do this until there are no more "delete".

Is there anyway to automate the process starting with the creation of the absolute column, and then making Excel do the whole filter, delete, apply the formula again, and over and over again?

I tried the automate function on Excel but honestly I'm don't know programming so I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: You'll be needing VBA for this, but one thing's very important: when deleting entries from a list, go through that list from end to beginning, never from beginning to end, or you'll not be able to delete succeeding entries.

Comment: Welcome Manuel! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!